# Submit button/function in AngularJS component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this component:

```
<div class="rtm-nav">
    <div ng-app>    
    <form ng-submit="$ctrl.submit">
        <label>From:
            <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="$ctrl.from">
        </label>
        <label>To:
            <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="$ctrl.to">
        </label>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Apply" />
    </form> 
    </div>
</div>
```

It's controller:

```
const rtmNav = {
    bindings: {
        from:'<',
        to:'<',
        submit: '&'
    },
    controller: angular.noop,
    templateUrl: require('./rtmNav.html')
}

export default rtmNav;
```

The controller of the main page:

```
class DemandCtrl {
    constructor(ChartDataService) {
        this.ChartDataService = ChartDataService;
        debugger;
        this.dataa = {
            from: '10/01/2017',
            to:  '10/03/2017'
        };
        this.submit = () => {
            console.log('tesst');
        };
    }

    $onInit() {
        getData.call(null, this);       
    }
}

function getData(DemandCtrl) {
    debugger;
    DemandCtrl.ChartDataService.getData(DemandCtrl.dataa).then(result => {
        DemandCtrl.result = result.data;
        getChart(result.data);
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
}

...

DemandCtrl.$inject = ['ChartDataService'];

export const Demand = {
    bindings: {
        data: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: demandPageHtml,
    controller: DemandCtrl
};
```

And here is the html of the main page:

```
<div class="demand page">   
    <rtm-header title="Demand" icon="fa fa-line-chart" link=true></rtm-header> 
    <rtm-nav from="$ctrl.dataa.from", to="$ctrl.dataa.to", submit="console.log('xxx')">         
    </rtm-nav> 
    <div id="chart" class="demand-chart">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run the application, the text inputs for `dataa.from` and `dataa.to` are populated with the hardcoded data I introduced (`10/01/2017` and `10/03/2017`).

The problem is with the Apply/submit button. When I click on it I'm expecting to see the message (`xxx`) in console but nothing happens.

Now it is written as `submit="console.log('xxx')"`, but I've tried also as `function{submit="console.log('xxx')};"` resulting in the following error:

> standalone.js:16 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' is an
>   unexpected token at column 9 of the expression
>   [function{console.log('xxx')] starting at [{console.log('xxx')].

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use functions like `console.log()` within the template, declare something into the controller and call it:

instead of

```
<rtm-nav from="$ctrl.dataa.from", to="$ctrl.dataa.to", submit="console.log('xxx')">
```

do

```
<rtm-nav from="$ctrl.dataa.from", to="$ctrl.dataa.to", submit="$ctrl.logSomething()">
```

and declare it inside the controller (of the view):

```
class DemandCtrl {
    constructor(ChartDataService) {
        this.ChartDataService = ChartDataService;
        debugger;
        this.dataa = {
            from: '10/01/2017',
            to:  '10/03/2017'
        };
        this.submit = () => {
            console.log('tesst');
        };
    }

    $onInit() {
        getData.call(null, this);       
    }

    logSomething() {
        console.log('www');
    }
}
```